# convert a md file in odt with correct name

Tags: filenames, conversion, dolphin, md

I added this command in Dolphin menu for convert a `.md` (Mark Down) file to `.odt` (Open Document Text ) file:

```
pandoc %U -o %F.odt
```

and I get the right file, but with *two* extension:

```
fileorig.md.odt
```

How can I get a file `fileorig.odt`?

Comment: all within dolphin, I'm assuming? There are many ways to rename a file afterwards, if that would suffice...?

Comment: rename automatically?

Answer (score 1):

My solution: `pandoc %U -o %u.odt && rename 's/md.odt/odt/g' *`
It works.